# Corrupted file - .xml2js.DELETE/package,json in node_modules within an Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-cli-v9, angular-devkit

### Errors began after updating to **Angular-Cli V10.1.0**.

### Initial problems I encountered:

- The `ng` command was not working. I found that core dependencies were missing:
  `npm WARN @angular/fire@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

### I Tried:

- Installing dependencies manually.
- Uninstalling the angular-cli globally, clearing the cache with --force, rebooting and reinstalling.
- Downloading latest NodeJs, updating npm using`npm update` as well as Angular: `ng update`.
- Deleting: `package.lock.json` ; `package.json` ; `node_modules`

### I could not delete node_modules:

- A folder: `.xml2js.DELETE` has a `package.json` file that can't be opened in my IDE or by Windows.
- I believe it's this file that's preventing me from running `npm install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EUREKA - Problem Solved!

Steps I took which fixed the issue:

- Open `Powershell` as administrator
- Run `chkdsk /f`
- Delete `node_modules`
- run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are able to successfully delete your entire node_modules folder a simple `npm install` will fix your issue.

1. Close all programs that could possible touching the file and attempt to delete it.
2. Attempt to delete it using the cmd line. If you are not already I suggest you use a cmd prompt like [Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) which will give you some of the linux cmd prompt tools in windows. Then try `rm -rf node_modules` from the correct directory.
3. If both of those don't work restart your computer, and attempt 1 & 2 again.
4. If none of those work boot into safe mode and once again attempt to remove the files.

You can go down a further rabbit hole to figure out how to delete that file but if you are in a time crunch you could just copy your entire project (minus the node_modules) to a new folder. Delete the package.lock.json and then `npm install`

Answer (score -1):

Using PowerShell in admin mode to run `chkdsk /f` worked for me.

I also had to restart my PC.

Then `SHIFT` + `DEL` the **node_modules** directory.

Worked like a piece of cake!

Comment: This solution is nearly identical to the one in the accepted answer, can you add more details on how it differs from that one?